# Grails Spock unit tests pass locally but fail in CI environment

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class, spock

I have a set of Spock based unit tests that are passing locally but failing with the two following exceptions being logged on my CI (Jenkins) server. Some tests fail with both exceptions, but some only fail with the first.

All tests fail with this exception:

```
Account field name is nullable using null(com.vsnap.site.entities.account.organization.OrganizationSpec)
|
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.grails.datastore.mapping.transactions.SessionHolder@7f5083c7] for key [org.grails.datastore.mapping.simple.SimpleMapDatastore@62987889] bound to thread [main]
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.bindSession(DatastoreUtils.java:337)
at grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin.connectDatastore(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:108)
at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension$FixtureType$FixtureMethodInterceptor.intercept(JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension.java:145)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:84)
at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
```

Some fail with this in addition to the first:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method isActive() on null object
at grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin.shutdownApplicationContext(GrailsUnitTestMixin.groovy:232)
at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension$FixtureType$FixtureMethodInterceptor.intercept(JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension.java:145)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:84)
at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
```

In these units tests, all I'm doing is testing the constraints on a domain object:

```
@TestFor(User)
class UserSpec extends Specification {
    def "test user field constraints"() {
        when:
        def user = new User(name: name)

        then:
        user.errors['name'] == error

        where:
        error      | name
        'blank'    | ''
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue was that I had not defined dependencies correctly according to the docs: http://grails.org/plugin/spock

Comment: Could you be more specific? I seem to have the dependencies defined correctly, but am having a similar issue when running the tests through IntelliJ (tests run fine from my console)

Comment: Running a 'grails clean' in the project folder from my command line seems to have fixed things, not sure what got corrupted but that appears to have been the issue!

Comment: I saw this issue early on, it disappeared for a time and now its back.... very frustrating. I see it using IntelliJ Junit test runner executing Spock tests that are mocking a Domain object. Cleaning did not seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I left a comment above I discovered that the stack trace is actually trying to tell me something useful :) 
The problem is that the same library is being pulled in by IntelliJ in my case and both instances are registering themselves with the listeners.... 
In my case Maven was pulling in grails-testing-plugin and also IntelliJ had grails folder containing the same jar on the dependency tree (module setting). Removing one of these took care of the problem ....now on to the next one :)